# bootstrap tooltip/popover on a button not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using php to authenticate a user login and I would like to show a popover/tooltip saying "invalid username or password" under the sign in button in case the user/password were invalid.

my php part is working, tested with echo, but I can't make the tooltip to work.

I have included the following import

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
```

created the following javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function invalid(){
$('#userNameField').tooltip({
              'selector': '',
              'placement': 'bottom',
              'content' : 'bbbbblblblbl'
            });
$('#userNameField').tooltip('show');
}
</script>
```

my button has the userNameField id

```
    <form class="navbar-form pull-right" action="" method="post">
      <input type="submit" class="btn" id="userNameField" value="Sign in">
    </form>
```

and my php stops before I am calling the invalid function (I tested this part with an alert("test") and it is working

```
?>
        <!--Code for invalid username/password combo goes here-->
   <script type="text/javascript">
    invalid();
    </script>
<?php
```

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tooltip doesnot have `content` property instead you need to use `title`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YfX4U/)

### [Doc](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

```
   $('#userNameField').tooltip({
              'placement': 'bottom',
              'title' : 'bbbbblblblbl'
            });

$('#userNameField').tooltip('show');
```

Comment: I guess I have another issue. I am trying to constantly present it after i click a button and my php code determine if a login is valid or not.

is it something that can be done with tooltip?

Comment: Tooltip is not intended for that you need to go with popover then to persist.. Or probably a workaround for that. But is it coming up atleast after the solution i provided in my answer.

Comment: No it does not. I don't know if this is due to the php or something else. I also changed my code to a popover,and it is not working

Comment: The issue is that php refresh the page, and as a result i can't see the tooltip :\. Is there a way to load it after a refresh ?

Comment: You could try using an AJAX call so that the page won't refresh

Comment: @Quantico if your page is getting refreshed there is no way DOM can retain any of the previous states itself, leave tooltip alone...